# How to create "Delete button for deleting grid columns from SQL Server database in C#"?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need a part of the code where I can delete a grid column or row from the database by clicking a `delete` button, and it should be done with C#.

I tried deleting it by MVVM architecture and I believe I wrote something wrong. Is there any other way to do this?

```
public void DeleteAuction()
{
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
     {
         conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ToString();
         conn.Open();

         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE AuctionTbl2 SET deleted = 1 WHERE id = @Id", conn);

         SqlParameter myParam = new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 11);
         myParam.Value = this.Id;

         command.Parameters.Add(myParam);

         int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

Now I made constructors, properties and fields, and that works okay. I tried to connect data from SQL Server to C#, that worked okay as well, but when I press the `delete` button it doesn't work. No errors, no nothing. Please help, I'm getting very desperate now.

[[image: This is when delete is clicked, it should go in DB from 0 --> 1 for deleted[1]]

[image: Like this]

Comment: How you are expecting to delete the record ? I mean you are just setting the value of `deleted` column to 1. You are not deleting it actually.

Comment: @ZainArshad I know that, so I made a class named RelayCommand that implements ICommand interface and I made _execute and _canExecute methods, now I made everything for this button, but again I can't manage to get it working somehow.

Comment: You have no need to write all these methods, I mean simply make a `stored procedure` that will do `update, delete, insert`,you just have to pass the arguments.

Comment: Is this some sort of homework? Why would you ever need to delete database columns from a gridview?

Comment: @Vilx- It is an assignment for my auction. In my school they told me to do so. I mean like that so please don't judge me xD.

Comment: @ZainArshad I know that, but I must do it like this because it is for a grade. I tried making it for a week and I'm so frustrated..

Comment: I'm not judging you. :) However, ouside of theorerical exercises, this is a very unusual thing to do. Deleting columns, I mean. Rows, sure. But columns - no. Anyways, the above code in and of itself is ok, so the problem is elsewhere. Do you refresh your grid after the delete? There's no way for it to know it automatically, you need to tell it to refresh the data. Or you need to manually remove the row from the grid (not the db). Or perhaps you've messed up the events and the above code isn't getting called?

Comment: Also, the above code doesn't actually delete the row from the db. It just sets the value in the `deleted` column to  1. That's ok, many systems do that. But then you need to remember to NOT show the rows where `deleted=1`. Are you filtering your grid like that?

Comment: @Vilx- So it is going like this. I'm deleting whole rows I mean, I don't need to delete like "id" but the id's number, and like I don't need to delete auctionName column, but only Auction name like Playstation 4 Slim idk..

Comment: @Vilx- it should go like this..

ID - Auction Name - Price - Bidder :
1  -  Playstation 4  -  640$ - xVenum

Comment: Ok, you're not making sense. Try slower, more detailed, and perhaps with examples.

Comment: @Vilx- I made it like MVVM architecture, for viewing a method through it and also to change it. I used some school examples and also some books like C# 7.0 by Jesse Liberty

Comment: @Vilx- I'll post a few pictures on imgur.

Comment: Maybe you can make up some fake screenshots where you _show_ what needs to happen? Something like "At first it looks like this, then I click that button  there, and then it should look like this, and in the database it should look like this."

Comment: You can include the pictures in your post.

Comment: If that's the only thing your `Delete` button does, then you're probably missing a refresh for the grid; you need to query your information again. Also make sure that the query or stored procedure that fills your grid ignores rows where deleted = 1

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** You should try this code, I have tested it personally at it is running like a charm. Do tell me if it gets you what you want.

```
public void DeleteAuction()
{
    try
    {
        bool isSuccess = false;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ToString();
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE AuctionTbl2 SET deleted = 1 WHERE id = @Id", conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id",Id);
            int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if(rows>0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Deletion Successfull");
                dt = selectAuction();
                auctionDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Deletion Unsuccessfull");
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}

//method to update the dataGridView after deletion
public DataTable selectAuction()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable(); 
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ToString();
            conn.Open();
            String sql = "select * from AuctionTbl2";          
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);         
            SqlDataAdapter adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);                                         
            adaptor.Fill(table);    
        }               
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);                 
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();                 
    }
    return table;
}
```

**NOTE:** I have tried to use variables just like yours, but if there is one *sneaky* different variable name, then pardon me.

Comment: Tried it as well, it says incorrect syntax near "=". In the line:

int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @xVenum.dll just tell me what you want ? Not what is error or what is not... you want to delete the row and then it should not be visible in your dataGriDView... am i right ? Tell me and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @xVenum.dll New users must take this to account, that if they find the answer correct and it resolves their issue, then kindly mark that as answer. so that if someone have the same issue in future they can get a handy help without asking a new question. That's how things work here . Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could approach the problem. 
1) Execute an SQL command to set the record's deleted column to one. Then rebind the DataGridView.
2) Delete the row from the DataGridView, then execute a SQL command to set the record's Deleted column to 1.

I like the number 2 option because it moves the least amount of data around. 
Assuming method 2, it would go something like this:

```
private void DeleteSale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
      var RowId = dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString(); 
    dataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex);


    using(var connection = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString")
    {
         using(var command = new SqlCommand("myStoredProcedureName", connection))
         {
              command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
              command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Id", RowId));
              command.Connection.Open();
              command.ExecuteNonQuery();
              command.Connection.Close();
          }
    }    
}
```

Just FYI: Never write inline SQL statements like that, always use parameter stored procedures.